# How to restart a dnx website in production?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I updated a `ASP.NET CORE/ASP.NET 5 RC1` controller `cs` file with a programming change.

The site has previously been deployed on production on `IIS7.5` Windows 2012 Server which makes use of `HTTPPlatformHandler` installed in IIS.
This is a remote server I have to access via VPN.
The site is setup as an application in IIS and the folder points to the `wwwroot` directory of the deployed site.

I deploy it currently by deploying it first locally by right clicking on my project in `Visual Studio 2015` and selecting publish to local folder. I then copy the contents of the local folder to the remote network IIS7.5 web server site folder.

If I copy for example the `appsettings.json` or a changed `.cs` file to the server, the change will not reflect.

If I copy the whole site to the production server I get folders and files in use messages. I have to kill the 'dnx' process in order to copy without getting these messages.

From my understanding if I kill the process dnx it will force a recompile. This is currently the only way I know of to restart the site after updating it but I imagine it is not the best way.

1. What is the standard practice to restart your website after you update your production sites that run `ASP.NET5 RC1`?
2. Also changing my `app.settings` json file aslo doesn't trigger a site reload like changing the `web.config` did in `ASP.NET 4` so being able to restart a site is important.
3. If I have multiple sites on the same `app pool` and I only want to update one in production. How can I only restart the one site to reflect the latest changes?
4. Is it possibly to restart the website to reflect the change as updating it directly doesn't cause a recompile taking into consideration if I only have access to a shared folder and not the web server itself?

Comment: You should add information on where you host it (Azure, VM, IIS, Linux?) and how you deploy it. At least deploying from VS to Azure App Service always restarts the App. Question is what is your deplyoment workflow?

Comment: updated the post. It is IIS as web server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `IISPlatformHandler`, DNX process is started by IIS (instructions are in `wwwroot\web.config`).

IIS knows nothing about your source files, all requests are forwarded to DNX.

DNX does NOT watch source files for changes, because there is no `dnx-watch` there.

IIS only watches for `wwwroot\web.config` file changes, so you need to change/edit/touch it to force IIS to restart website (and DNX process).

Comment: I will have to test this. How do I deploy a site then if it says the site is in use when I copy over the local deployment folder to the server ISS site folder? ASP.NET 4 didn't have an "files in use issue" when one simply copies over files

Comment: What exact files are 'in use' ? With my website, I can easily overwrite .cs and .chtml and other files... The only locked files are dnx runtime dlls and dependencies, but they do not need to be updated frequently.

Comment: Yes it is dlls in use. Pity publish doesn't have an exclude dll option. I will have to do some test as with my site I found that when copying over the site and ignore the files in use without killing dnx and then typing in the url in the browser caused an indefinite loading in my browser. I could only solve it by killing dnx.

Answer (score 1):

I use [msdeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) to deploy, it has commands to stop and start app pools, using these commands has resolved my file in use errors. There are lots of ways to use [msdeploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy), below is how I happen to be using it.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="site/pool",recycleMode="StopAppPool",computername=COMPUTERNAME
msdeploy -source:contentPath='SOURCE PATH' -dest:contentPath='\\COMPUTERNAME\wwwroot\' -verb:sync -retryAttempts:2 -disablerule:BackupRule
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:recycleApp -dest:recycleApp="site/pool",recycleMode="StartAppPool",computername=COMPUTERNAME
```

Comment: you could have a scenario where multiple sites use the same app pool and you need to update a site without affecting the other sites. You can't then update then restart the app pool. Ideally one only wants to update your site.

Comment: @greay Agreed, this doesn't solve that - not sure if that situation is possible since IIS is only really a reverse proxy now and the actual .NET process is separate.